# What are the array_key_exists() and array_search() equivalents for objective-c NSArrays?

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa

1. I have this bug in Obj-C that is caused because the program is trying to access a non-existing NSArray key.
2. Typically in my PHP programs I verify that a key exists before using it using array_key_exists(NEEDLE, HAYSTACK).
3. Is there an equivalent in Cocoa / Obj-C for these two functions, and if not, how would you go about creating these.
4. I am more interested in a solution for array_key_exists() than in array_search().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an NSArray, keys can only be integers. So you can simply check whether the index you are trying to access is less than the number of items in the array. You can check the number of items via the count method:

```
NSArray *array = ... some array ... 
NSUInteger index = ... some index ...

if (index < [array count]) {
     // It's safe to do [array objectAtIndex:index]
}
```

Comment: Right. Of course, if the OP really wants non-integer "keys", he should be using NSDictionary...

Comment: I completely agree with @DavidGelhar , if the use of keys is so important, then dictionary is the best choice, that way you won't have to worry about having an order in the collection, but simply if the key for a specific object exists.

Comment: Yup - I agree with you both. But the OP asked about NSArray, so I answered about that. If he/she does want to use non-integer keys than an NSDictionary is the way to go.

Comment: +1 @DavidGelhar for the recommendation. I'll see if it is an alternative.

Comment: @DavidGelhar In traditional PHP Arrays, when array items don't explicitly define a key, they are automatically assigned a numerical key, can be accessed thru such key, and that key is searchable thru the functions that I mentioned. I guess that with Obj-C there's no such thing as an "hybrid array" and that keys are better dealt with the NSDictionary.

Comment: @triangle_man The solution then is really to use NSDictionary, but because you provided the best solution possible given the question's constraints first, I'm accepting your solution. I've upped and commented the other posters solutions as the most elegant solution though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP “arrays” and Cocoa “arrays” are not the same thing.

In Cocoa, an “array” is a flat, ordered collection of values. Each value's position in the array is called its index. This is the same sense as a C “array”.

In PHP, an “array” is an associative array, mapping keys to values. Another term for this is *dictionary*, and that is what Cocoa calls it: Cocoa's class for this is NSDictionary.

So what you want is an NSDictionary, not an NSArray.

The counterpart to `array_key_exists` is `objectForKey:`: If the key does not exist in the dictionary, `objectForKey:` returns `nil`.

The counterpart to `array_search` is `allKeysForObject:`.

Answer (score 1):

In php, array_key_exists is for "associative" arrays or hashes, or as Objective-C calls them "Dictionaries". So you should use:

> NSDictionary
>   or
>   NSMutableDictionary

So you could do something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dItems = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dItems dItems: @"Key" forKey: @"Value"];
[dItems dItems: @"Key2" forKey: @"Value2"];
if ([dItems valueForKey: "Key"] != nil) {
 // exists
}
```

NSDictionary is much more efficient then iterating through an array every time, and has lots

of valuable functions you can fin at: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at the "Finding Objects in an Array" section of the [NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

`-indexOfObject:` or `-indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Those methods assume that you are searching the array to see if an object that already exists in the current scope, also exists in the target array. I don't have the object on the local scope to use as a search key. I am retrieving THAT object from the array using a numeric key. Those won't work, thanks.

Comment: Really sounds like you're wanting to use an `NSDictionary` instead of `NSArray` then. Arrays are always indexed sequentially starting at 0, so if you have an array with 3 elements they will always be indexed 0, 1, and 2. So, the (rough) equivalent of `array_key_exists` is to simply check the count of how many items are in the array (as triangle_man said). I say "rough", because NSArrays are really not the same as PHP arrays; you can't "retrieve...from the array using a numeric key" unless the "key" is the index position in the array.

Comment: looks like we came to the same conclusion at the same time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject`

More details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject%3a)

Comment: Can't use that (see my reply to @David Gelhar). I'm currently using `value = [myNSArray objectAtIndex: rowIndex];` I need to check if `rowIndex` exists before attempting to retrieve it with `objectAtIndex:`.